# Reading / Enumerating registry path fails "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Telephony\\Country/region List"

Tags: c++, windows, registry, atl

I want to enumerate the registry path.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Telephony\Country/region List
```

I can open and enumerate

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Telephony\
```

But enumerating the node

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Telephony\Country/region List
```

causes an error 2! Not found. Also enumerating the node

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Telephony\
```

doesn't show the subnode shown in RegEdit

```
ASSERT(CRegKey{}.Open(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, _T("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Telephony"), KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS)==ERROR_SUCCESS);
ASSERT(CRegKey{}.Open(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, _T("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Telephony\\Country/region List\\1"), KEY_READ)==ERROR_SUCCESS);
ASSERT(CRegKey{}.Open(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, _T("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Telephony\\Country/region List"), KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS)==ERROR_SUCCESS);
    
    if (regKey.Open(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, _T("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Telephony"), KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS)==ERROR_SUCCESS)
//  if (regKey.Open(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, _T("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Telephony\\Country/region List"), KEY_READ)==ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        // Loop over all entries
        for (DWORD dwIndex = 0; ; ++dwIndex)
        {
            TCHAR szCountry[64];
            DWORD dwLen = MfxCountOf(szCountry);
            if (regKey.EnumKey(dwIndex, szCountry, &dwLen)!=ERROR_SUCCESS)
                break;
```

What is the problem with this node?

Answer (score 0):

Oh man... the answer is simple. I have a 32bit program, and this node can't be read from 32bit. It isn't mapped.

I have to use the `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` flag to get access to it.